# Why does this @JsonIgnore fix my infinite loop?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have attempted to create a parent-child relationship of the same entity type. A problem I was facing was that when trying to do a GET request to retrieve an entity where the children are not empty, I would get a stack overflow error, from what looks like an infinite loop. After some looking around I found a fix by simply adding a @JsonIgnore to the parent field in the Entity class. My question is why does this fix that issue? What was the issue to begin with?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trash")
public class Trash {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String message;

    private Long likes;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Trash parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Trash> children;
```

Here is the error I was receiving

```
2019-07-19 10:29:55.867 ERROR 14156 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]-
repeats for awhile....
>com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception explains that :

```
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) 
(through reference chain: 
>com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]-
>com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]-
>org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]- >com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]-
>com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]-
>org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-
>com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]-
>com.example.litter.model.Trash$HibernateProxy$lBPNIlf1["children"]-
>org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-
>com.example.litter.model.Trash["parent"]-
and so for...
```

The `parent` field serialization triggers the `children` field serialization that itself 
triggers the `parent` field serialization, and so for...
That may look abstract enough, so here is a concrete example.

Suppose these three `Trash` instances  : one parent that has two children.

> Trash-1 (children = 2,3)
>
> Trash-2 (parent : 1)
>
> Trash-3 (parent : 1)

Suppose you want to serialize `Trash-1` (the parent).
Here is how Jackson proceeds :

1) Jackson tries to serialize  `Trash-1` fields, which the `children`  field (`Trash-2` and `Trash-3`) that interest us.
So it starts the `children` serialization.
2) But to serialize `Trash-2`, Jackson also needs to serialize its fields, which the `parent` field that is `Trash-1` !
3) We go back to the first step.

And it goes on until that the recursion be too important and Jackson stops you.

By annotating `parent` or `children` with `@JsonIgnore`, you ask to Jackson to skip one of both serialization and so it breaks the recursion.
For example on `parent`, it would give :

1) Jackson tries to serialize  `Trash-1` fields, which the `children`  field (`Trash-2` and `Trash-3`) that interest us.
So it starts the `children` serialization.
2) `Trash-2` is serialized (no `parent` field serialization required).
2) `Trash-3` is serialized (no `parent` field serialization required).

And it is done.

Comment: Thank you! Now knowing this, is it possible for me to obtain both the parent and children data for a Trash with a get request using this model? A 'Trash' is essentially the same as a tweet, so I want to be able to show the replies for a Trash and the conversation leading to that Trash

Comment: Of course. You have multiple ways : reassociate them in the client side that consumes the JSON. For each parent you know its children. So by iterating on the children of the parent, you can set their parent. Another approach would be to use a JSON custom serializer that would serialize the `parent` field as an Integer or a String representing its id (`@JsonSerialize` on the field)

Answer (score 3):

You had an infinite loop because each instance of your class references both its parent and its children.

So, in order to serialize a child, you have to serialize its parent, and in order to serialize the parent you have to serialize its children. Including the child you began with.

The tag @JsonIgnore you added fixes this problem because now to serialize a child you don't need to serialize its parent. There's no infinite loop any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular reference between you parent and child objects: each refer to each other. Since the JSON is produced by expanding any referenced objects (no references), you'll get an infinite hierarchy through the parent/children fields.

When you ignore one of the fields (parent in your case), the traversal is only towards children, but not back, so it's not circular anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. It is called: **"Jackson infinite recursion problem"**. Using @JsonIgnore is one of the possible solutions to solve the infinite recursion problem. People left really good answer on this post on why @JsonIgnore solves the infinite loop; however, if you would like more info or  check another solutions for this issue visit this [site](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).